# Сортировка массива объектов по нескольким значениям ключей

Tags: javascript

Получаю массив объектов, по которым в цикле строю таблицу:

```
arr = [ 
    {'color':'blue'},
    {'color':'pink'},
    {'color':'green'},
    {'color':'pink'},
    {'color':'blue'},
    {'color':'red'},
    {'color':'green'},
    {'color':'pink'}
]
```

Нужна фильтрация, чтобы все обьекты с цветом pink шли всегда первыми, потом с цветом green, потом все остальные.
Сделал это так, но мне кажется не очень рационально

```
let filteredArray = [];
let pinkFilter = arr.filter((i)=> i.color==='pink');
if (pinkFilter.length) {filteredArray.push(...pinkFilter)};
let greenFilter = arr.filter((i)=> i.color==='green');
if (greenFilter.length) {filteredArray.push(...greenFilter)};
let otherColors = arr.filter((i)=> i.color !=='pink' && i.color !=='green');
if (otherColors.length) {filteredArray.push(...otherColors )};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let arr = [ 
  {'color':'blue'},
  {'color':'pink'},
  {'color':'green'},
  {'color':'pink'},
  {'color':'blue'},
  {'color':'red'},
  {'color':'green'},
  {'color':'pink'}
];

function getHashCode(color) {
  /*
  let codes = { pink: 1, green: 2 };
  // если цвет не pink и не green, 
  // (codes[color] вернет undefined, a выражение codes[color] || 100 вернет 100) 
  // возвращаем большое число - другие цвета идут в конец сортированного массива
  return codes[color] || 100;
  */
  // можно в одну строку:
  return { pink: 1, green: 2 }[color] || 100;
}

// сортируем исходный массив
arr.sort((a, b) => getHashCode(a.color) - getHashCode(b.color));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: ать, не успел :(

Comment: @teran Grundy помешал?

Comment: :D, но у меня все равно менее элегантный вариант был. так что плюс. с `|| 100` хитро (:

Comment: а можно написать комментарии с обяснением к коду. я не понял ничего начиная вот с этой части __return codes__

Comment: @Demon__ANT а теперь?

Comment: @Igor спасибо большое без обяснений я бы днями думал над этим кодом.Добавил плюсик. :)

Answer (score 2):

**1.Шаг** Берем розовые (`pink`) цвета

**2.Шаг** Потом зеленые (`green`)

**3.Шаг** проверяем не осталось ли в массиве других значений кроме розовых и зеленых

**4.Шаг** Конкатенируем все массивы в один.

```js
let arr = [ 
        {'color':'blue'},
        {'color':'pink'},
        {'color':'green'},
        {'color':'pink'},
        {'color':'blue'},
        {'color':'red'},
        {'color':'green'},
        {'color':'pink'}
]

let arrPink = arr.filter(i => i.color === "pink"); 
let arrGreen = arr.filter(i => i.color === "green");
let allArr = arr.filter(i => i.color !== "pink" && i.color !== "green");
console.log([...arrPink, ...arrGreen, ...allArr]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [ 
    {'color':'blue'},
    {'color':'pink'},
    {'color':'green'},
    {'color':'pink'},
    {'color':'blue'},
    {'color':'red'},
    {'color':'green'},
    {'color':'pink'}
];

let sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  let order = ['green', 'pink']; // тут порядок цветов обратен желаемому
  let pos1 = order.indexOf(a.color);
  let pos2 = order.indexOf(b.color);
  return pos2 - pos1;
})

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: А если будет нужно третий цвет зафиксировать, например, красный, с sort не получится?

Comment: в начало `order`добавьте и будет работать.

Comment: Почему не получится? Просто добавить его в массив `order`, и все. Но у @Igor решение поизящнее. :)

Comment: А, точно, спасибо Вам) Да, с хешем у @Igor круто получилось ;)